# ValueError: `multiple` must be one of ['layer', 'stack', 'fill', 'dodge'], but s was passed.`

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

I am trying to stack my histplot FaceGrid plot with "multiple" in "hue_kws"

```
fg1 = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col="type", col_wrap=3, hue="class", height=3.5,
                    hue_kws={"multiple": 'stack'}
                    )
fg1.map_dataframe(sns.histplot, x="col_name")
```

I get the error in the title. If I pass

> `hue_kws={"multiple": 'layer'}`

the error changed to

```
ValueError: `multiple` must be one of ['layer', 'stack', 'fill', 'dodge'], but l was passed.`
```

So I guess only the first letter of the string of the value is passed.
What am I missing?

Comment: it shouldn't matter, but could you just try `hue_kws={"multiple":"stack"}`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tired it but it does not seem to have any impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `hue_kws` incorrectly. Its [parameter type](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) documentation has "dictionary of param -> list of values mapping". So it is trying to use the first letter of your string for the first hue level, the second letter of your string for the second hue variable, etc. This is not what you want.

While you can use `FacetGrid` directly, it's simpler, and safer, to use `displot`:

```
fg1 = sns.displot(df, x="col_name", hue="class",
                  col="type", col_wrap=3,
                  height=3.5, multiple="stack")
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently hit the issue, and resolved by passing in a list of values, one for each facet.
In this case:
hue_kws={"multiple": ['stack']*df.class.nunique()} should work.